# Taking `struct page` of PCI region

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a kernel module (2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64, in VirtualBox).
I try to get `struct page` corresponding to the physical address `0xf0000000`, which seems to be in PCI region (`/proc/iomem` shows `f0000000-f001ffff : 0000:00:03.0`).

```
unsigned long phys = 0xf0000000;
struct page *p = pfn_to_page(phys >> PAGE_SHIFT);
printk(KERN_NOTICE "page %p", p); // shows ffffea0003480000
```

However, it doesn't appear to be a valid pointer, as every attempt to access `p` fields crashes the system (total freeze).

What's wrong with the above code? Don't PCI address ranges have the appropriate `struct page`'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no `struct page`s for this area, as explained in LDD3:
 [PCI memory is mapped above the highest system memory, and there are no entries in the system memory map for those addresses.](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-2)